# file found from one .cpp file, but give "No such file or directory" from another .cpp file

Tags: c++, netbeans

in CCellBridge.cpp, CCellBridge.h is found
but in main.cpp, CCellBridge.h gives:

```
main.cpp:15:25: fatal error: CCellBridge.h: No such file or directory
  #include "CCellBridge.h"
```

i even copy/paste

```
#include "CCellBridge.h"
```

from CCellBridge.cpp into main.cpp

in main.cpp, it will see the functions from CCellBridge.h

i have cleaned/compiled, closed, clean/compiled, but the error still shows.
how can the IDE see the class, but the compiler can not?
both files are in same project.
i have closed file and opened file in project just to make sure it was the correct file.

this is in main, it sees it. no yellow or red lines under code.

```
CCellBridge cellBridge = new CCellBridge();
cellBridge.GetFire();
```

type

```
cellBridge.
```

and list of functions show up

yet

```
#include "CCellBridge.h"
```

in main.cpp has yellow line under it

guess this needs clarifying:
file CCellBridge.cpp

```
 //
 #include "CCellBridge.h"

 CCellBridge::CCellBridge()
 {

 }
```

works

file main.cpp

```
 #include <cstdlib>
 #include "CCellBridge.h"

 using namespace std;

 int main(int argc, char** argv) 
 {
     CCellBridge cellBridge = new CCellBridge();
     return 0;
 }
```

does not work

file main.cpp

```
 #include <cstdlib>
 #include "CCellBridge.h"

 using namespace std;

 int main(int argc, char** argv) 
 {
     CCellBridge cellBridge = new CCellBridge();
     cellBridge.  [note: this give list of function in class CCellBridge]
     return 0;
 }
```

Comment: `#include "CCellBridge.h"` typically implies that this file is located in the same directory as the file including it (that is `main.cpp`). Check the folder structure of your project on disc.

Comment: it is in same project. CCellBridge.h works in CCellBridge.cpp

Comment: well. when i imported the files to project, it did not put the file in project folder.

Comment: Have you verified, outside of netbeans, that main.cpp is in the same directory as  CellBridge.cpp , and that directory also contains CellBridge.h ? If main.cpp and CellBridge.cpp reside in separate directories, you need to set the Include Directories to point to whichever directory CellBridge.h is in.

Comment: yah. i verified that it was NOT in same folder. had to remove files from project, copy files to project folder, add files to project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i verified that it was NOT in same folder. had to remove files from project, copy files to project folder, add files to project.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the include directories path properly in the Project Settings in your IDE(assuming its Visual Studio).
Open C/C++ General tab in VS IDE and check against the first entry "Additional Include Directories". The directory containing "CCellBridge.h" should be present in this list.
Let me know if this helps!!

Comment: tags are  c++ netbeans

Comment: it is the same project. why would it have to be manually added to any directory/path?

Comment: Sorry for that- I replied on basis of my assumption that you were using VS(which was a wrong assumption).